# How to change ASP.NET Boilerplate Angular Template UI Theme (Adminbsb)

Tags: themes, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm starting a project with ASP.NET Boilerplate Angular Template but I want to change the UI theme for another as Core UI theme.

someone who has worked with ASP.NET Boilerplate Angular Template could help me?

Comment: I am interested as well since I am facing several issues trying to install another theme in place of Admin BSB. Have had to restart it several times. The existing layout is "too coupled" it seems and breaking it off has been a real pain for me so far.

Comment: why do you think it's hard to replace? AdminBSB theme was replaced totally in 2 days.

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu That is great! Could you give me some advice that I should keep in mind during the replacement?

Comment: a teammate did the work but I know it was something like 2 days thing.

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu Thank you. It's good to know that the effort required is not as much as it seems

Comment: @FacundoRodriguez Did you figure out how to replace the theme?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the template in many times and what I dit was put all elements of new template in relative route in abp's base template, then after that I design again the default registers (Login screen, register, users, roles, tenant) because the HTML changes, I do the changes in at least 1 hour

(My english is not very well.)

Comment: Thank you José! Muchas gracias

Comment: Jose can you give more details please?

Comment: Any document on this?