# How to replace free BSB aspnetboilerplate theme

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I want to replace the free BSB theme in aspnetboilerplate project (Angular + ASP.NET Core) with a custom theme. Are there any instructions of how to do it?
Or at least a clue of what needs to be updated on client side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change ASP.NET Boilerplate Angular Template UI Theme (Adminbsb)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48255823/8601760)

Answer (score 2):

I've changed the bsb template in a lot times and what do is the next:

1. Put the new template elements in the `Abp's` angular project in the same place that it in the new template, for example if en `src/app` there is an `"Example"` folder I copy this to the `Abp's` template
2. Delete `Bsb` theme (if you have problem with `tenant`, `user`, or `roles` foler, erase it too) folder and find the places where `Abp's` project use, regular is in `angular.json`
3. Edit `Package.json` file and put all packages from new template without erase the packages from the `abp's` orignal `Package.json` file, angular will say you which files are repeated on the file, then you keep the most recent.
4. Do the same with `Angular.josn` file, be sure to load all files that load the new template.
5. Design again the base register from `abp's` template based on the new template, for example if your new template has a example login page, on the .ts you put the code of the orignal `abp's` template, like this you will have the new design with same `abp's` logic.

https://github.com/domisysdo/Colegio.Client

In this project I've putted Adminca Template on `Abp's` project you can download it and check it if it can help you.